# Infinite loop in React with useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use useReducer hook to maintain state. When my page is scrolled, I want to apply a set of styles and when I click a button I want to revert to initial styles .But for some reason I keep running into an infinite loop and cannot figure where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import SearchFilter from "./SearchFilter";
const initial = {
  searchFilter: "scale-100 bottom-0",
  navItems: "scale-y-100 scale-x-100 duration-500 top-1/4",
  background: "h-40 bg-black",
  searchBox: "opacity-0 scale-110",
};

function FinalNavigation() {
  const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "normal":
        return {
          ...state,
          searchFilter: "scale-100 bottom-0",
          navItems: "scale-y-100 scale-x-100 duration-500 top-1/4",
          background: "h-40 bg-black",
          searchBox: "opacity-0 scale-110",
        };

      case "scrolled":
        return {
          ...state,
          searchFilter: "scale-0 bottom-1/2",
          navItems: "scale-y-0 scale-x-0 duration-500 delay-75",
          background: "h-20 bg-slate-100",
          searchBox: "opacity-100 scale-100 duration-500 delay-75",
        };
    }
  };

  const [style, dispatch] = useReducer(navReducer, initial);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(style)}
      <div
        className={ ${style.background} `}
      >
        <Navigation
          searchTransform={style.searchBox}
          navTransform={style.navItems}
          searchClick={dispatch({ type: "scrolled" })}
    
        />
        <div
          className={`${style.searchFilter}`}
        >
          <SearchFilter />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={dispatch({ type: "normal" })}
       >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default FinalNavigation;
```

Comment: Just taking a stab, but I am thinking  you missing arrow function here `         searchClick={() => dispatch({ type: "scrolled" })}
` and here too: ` onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "normal" })}`

Comment: I would assume dispatch is called for every render right now and triggering an update of the state of useReducer hence a new re-render and infinite loop

Comment: That's it. Silly of me to miss that detail. Anyway thanks. You've been very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const handleOnSearch = () => dispatch({ type: "scrolled" })
 
const handleOnClick = () => dispatch({ type: "normal" });

return (
    <>
      {console.log(style)}
      <div
        className={ ${style.background} `}
      >
        <Navigation
          searchTransform={style.searchBox}
          navTransform={style.navItems}
          searchClick={handleOnSearch}
    
        />
        <div
          className={`${style.searchFilter}`}
        >
          <SearchFilter />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleOnClick}
       >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </>
  );
```

Would that work?

Basically, in your code `dispatch` is being called as soon as you render the component. And triggers and updates of the state, that triggers a new render, and hence an infinite loop.
You want to declare the function but only call it in response to the event. That is why you need to wrap it in an arrow function and only call dispatch when the event is called. Exactly what Kevin said above in comments.

Comment: Yes. I should have used a function when calling dispatch :)